# parse csv with commas, double quotes and encoding

Tags: ruby, parsing, encoding, csv

I'm using ruby 1.9 to parse the following csv file with **MacRoman** character

```
# encoding: ISO-8859-1
#csv_parse.csv
Name, main-dialogue
"Marceu", "Give it to him ó he, his wife."
```

I did the following to parse this.

```
require 'csv'
input_string = File.read("../csv_parse.rb").force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
 #=> "Name, main-dialogue\r\n\"Marceu\", \"Give it to him  \x97 he, his wife.\"\r\n"

data = CSV.parse(input_string, :quote_char => "'", :col_sep => "/\",/")
 #=> [["Name, main-dialogue"], ["\"Marceu", " \"Give it to him  \x97 he, his wife.\""]]
```

So, the **problem** is the second array in data is of single string rather than 2 strings like:
`["\"Marceu\"", " \"Give it to him  \x97 he, his wife.\""]]`
I tried with `:col_sep => ","` (which is the default behaviour) but it gave me 3 splits.

```
header = CSV.parse(input_string, :quote_char => "'")[0].map{|a| a.strip.downcase unless a.nil? }
 #=> ["Name", "main-dialogue"]
```

I've to parse again for the header as there's no double quote here.

The output is intented to be shown in browser again, so character `ó` should show up as usual and not as `\x97` or other.

Is there any way to solve the above problems?

Comment: Why are you using [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#ISO-8859-1) when you know the encoding is [MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacRoman)? They're not the same thing.

Comment: Thanx for pointing it out. I tried it with MacRoman but the result is same giving me single split instead of two.
I wanted to get as much latin characters coverage as possible which led me to choose ISO-8859-1 which gave `input_string.valid_encoding?` as well. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you do have [MacRoman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacRoman) encoded data; if you do this in `irb`:

```
>> "\x97".force_encoding('MacRoman').encode('UTF-8')
```

you get this:

```
=> "ó"
```

And that seems to be the character that you're expecting. So you want this:

```
input_string = File.read("../csv_parse.rb").force_encoding('MacRoman').encode('UTF-8')
```

Then you have two columns in your CSV, the columns are quoted with double quotes (so you don't need `:quote_char`), and the delimiter is `', '` so this should work:

```
data = CSV.parse(input_string, :col_sep => ", ")
```

and `data` will look like this:

```
[
    ["Name", "main-dialogue"],
    ["Marceu", "Give it to him  ó he, his wife."]
]
```

Comment: Thanx for the solution, I knew I was close. :) BTW i was trying to switch MacRoman with the source csv file encoding, can we detect it?

Comment: @zoras: Detecting encoding is difficult and usually a bunch of guess work. UTF-8 has internal structure that you can try to detect, other character sets have gaps in different places (e.g. MacRoman has 0x80 but ISO-8859-1 does not), etc. There is [rchardet](https://github.com/kirillrdy/rchardet) but I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're using the `:quote_char` and `:col_sep` options incorrectly.

The first should be that character that is used to enclose fields, i.e. `'"'` for the data you've shown, and `:col_sep` should just be `","`

The double quotes shown in your last example is just ruby formatting the output for you.

Comment: I tried it but I get this error..
`ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1895:in block (2 levels) in shift': Illegal quoting on line 2. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)`

Comment: Users of my app upload the csv file and few of them want encoding support. So, I'm checking for `input_string.valid_encoding?` and converting them to ISO-8859-1 as above. For UTF-8, I've just read the file. Isn't this the right way?